# Get a list of the last posts grouped by author and filtered by category

Tags: wp-query, query, mysql

i need a list of the latest post published by various authors, but filtered by category, like for example the latest posts of author that write about music.

i wrote this query and looks like working in mysql

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    INNER JOIN 
        wp_term_relationships ON $wpdb->posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
    WHERE 
        wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = 7
        AND
        $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'

    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
)
AS x GROUP BY post_author
```

*(the 7 is just an example category id)*

i just would like to know the other `$wpdb` functions to call the `wp_term_relationships` table and if is there something wrong with this query

thank you in advance

Comment: What's wrong with plain old [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)?

Comment: that i need just the last post written by each author and filtered by a category, like i need the last post by each author writing about _music_

Comment: You can get a reference to the wp_term_relationship with $wpdb->term_relationships. More https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L337